# Incompatible Plugin with Gallery2

Tags: php, content-management-system, gallery, themes, incompatibility

Using [Gallery2](http://gallery.menalto.com/) a standard gallery system I use I just installed on one of my websites. I then used a pretty simple Clean theme for including a header.php and footer.php files to match the same layout as the main website.

However, when I installed the theme/plugin I was prompted with this:

`Clean theme based on Siriux.net Gallery theme

Incompatible plugin!

Core API Required: 7.20 (available: 7.18)

Plugin API Required: 2.4 (available: 3.5)`

Is there a config file that I can trick so it believes they are compatible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just editing the Siriux theme.